# MySql++ Installation Linux 12.04 LTS

Tags: mysql++

The mysql++ package that comes from tangentsoft, is version 3.1.0 and I am having trouble building on my linux system. To get it to configure I had to specify the with the flag

./configure --with-mysql-lib=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/

Otherwise there was a problem with it finding the mysqlclient library. Now unfortunately it wont make, the error I get is ./lib/refcounted.h:258:2: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type, after I type make and before I type make install.

Has anyone had the same problem with compiling it, and did you find a solution?

Any help it solving this problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few `#include` fixes in the `svn` version of MySQL++ that haven't yet been included in a release version. They're necessary on modern OSes like yours, which include recent GCCs and `libstdc++`'s.

Don't be nervous about using the `svn` version in production. It's quite stable at the moment. My reasons for not releasing it as-is aren't related to stability.